# How to disable multi sort on specific column (single column sort should be enabled) [AG grid]

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Columns:

```
[
{
"field":"Athlete",
"sortable":true
},
**{
"field":"Age",
"sortable":true
},**
{
"field":"Country",
"sortable":true
}
...
...
]
```

In the above columns how to disable multi sort only on **Age** column in ag-grid (https://www.ag-grid.com/).

Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/n1xpnjPktEaHet4f?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

[image: Ag grid multi sort]

Comment: What is the kind of sort you want to allow on the age column? Could you define what you mean by preventing multi sort on age?

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly Age column can be single column sort, If user sorts only on Age column, sorting should work fine

Comment: In ag grid there is option to disbale multi sort for all columns, here I want to disable only for specific columns.

Comment: What I understood is,
1. When age column is selected, multisort should be disabled
2. When other columns are sorted, `age` column should be disabled for multisort
3. Age column should always available for single sort
Is it right understanding?

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar right

Comment: @cnsnaveen can you please have a look at the solution that I provided?

Answer (score 1):

What I understood is

1. When the `age` column is selected, `multisort` should be disabled
2. When other columns are sorted, the `age` column should be disabled for multisort
3. Age column should always be available for single sort Is it right
   understanding?

You can achieve the above behavior by using a combination of events on grid `onSortChanged` and `keyup/keydown` event. And update the `sortable` property of `columnDef` using `api.setColumnDef(columnDefs)` method.

### Rough Logic for `updateColumnDef`

Basically this logic changes `sortable` property of `columnDefs`

1. Separately keep a track of `Ctrl` button is pressed logic
2. **when** no Ctrl button is pressed **then** Keep all columns `sortable: true`
3. **when** Ctrl + `age` column is not sorted **then** mark `age` column
   `sortable: false`
4. **when** Ctrl + age column selected **then** Keep other
   columns `sortable: false`

### trackCtrlKey

```
@HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
trackCtrlKey(event) {
  if (this.isCtrl === event.ctrlKey) {
    return;
  }
  this.isCtrl = event.ctrlKey;
  this.updateColDef();
}
```

### Register `onSortChanged` event using `gridOptions` attribute

```
gridOptions = {
 onSortChanged: (e) => {
   this.updateColDef();
 },
};
```

### updateColumnDef

```
updateColDef() {
  const columnDefs = this.grid.columnApi.columnModel.getColumnDefs();
  const displayedColumns = this.grid.columnApi.columnModel.displayedColumns;
  const sortedColumns = displayedColumns.filter((col) => !!col.sort);
  const isAgeSorted = sortedColumns.find((col) => col.colId === 'age');
  // Keep all column sortable
  // 1. no Ctrl
  if (!this.isCtrl) {
    columnDefs.forEach((colDef) => (colDef.sortable = true));
  } else 
  if ((this.isCtrl && !isAgeSorted)) {
    // 2. Ctrl + age is not sorted
    const ageColumn = columnDefs.find((col) => col.colId === 'age');
    ageColumn.sortable = false;
  } else 
  // Keep other column sortable = false when
  // 1. Ctrl + age column selected
  if (this.isCtrl && isAgeSorted){
    columnDefs.forEach((colDef) => (colDef.sortable = colDef.colId === 'age'));
  }
  this.grid.columnApi.columnModel.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
}
```

Whoa!! if everything is wired together, it works as expected. It was nice learning to solve this issue.

[**Working Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/kCytXFhiG32hZAQD?preview)

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to disable the sortable option for that column by setting `sortable=false`:

```
[
{
"field":"Athlete",
"sortable":true
},
**{
"field":"Age",
"sortable":false
},**
{
"field":"Country",
"sortable":true
}
...
...
]
```

In the file app.component.ts you can do it like this:

```
  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    ...
    { field: 'age', width: 100, sortable:false},
    ....
  ];
```

I tested it with your app and it's working like you asked in your question.

Comment: I want to disbale only multi sort on age column, single coulmn sort should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since sortable parameter is accepting only a boolean and not a callback function, you have to implement your own custom header.
Have a look at [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-header/) documentation, your **onSortRequest** method should implement your own logic such:

```
onSortRequested(order: string, event: any) {
    const sortModel = this.columnsApi.getColumnState();
    const allSorted = sortModel.filter(el=>el.sort!=null);
    const suppressAgeSorting = allSorted.length>0;
    if(suppressAgeSorting) //override default sort parameters before applying set sort
        this.params.setSort(order, event.shiftKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for ag-grid

```
// enable sorting on 'name' and 'age' columns only
this.columnDefs = [
    { field: 'name', sortable: true },
    { field: 'age', sortable: true },
    { field: 'address' },
];

// disable sorting on 'name' and 'age' columns only
this.columnDefs = [
    { field: 'name', sortable: false},
    { field: 'age', sortable: false },
    { field: 'address' },
];
```

ag-grid official website documents with below link

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-sorting/

Answer (score 0):

I think its:

```
[
{
"field":"Athlete",
"sortable":false
},
**{
"field":"Age",
"sortable":false
},**
{
"field":"Country",
"sortable":false
}
...
...
]
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?